# Django FileField Retrieval of saved file onto a Hyperlink

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to  create a button to download a File that is saved as a part of a model.

Code below:

Model

```
class ResourceFile(models.Model):
resourceID = models.ForeignKey(Resource)
fileTitle = models.CharField(max_length=128)
fileDescription = models.CharField(max_length=256)
fileObject = models.FileField(upload_to='resourceFile')
active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Template - rfile is the ResourceFile instance.

```
<a id="rfile-{{ rfile.id }}" href="{{ rfile.fileObject.url }}" download><button type="button">{{ rfile }}</button></a>
```

When the button is clicked I get a File not found exception.
Any ideas?

Comment: Are `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` properly defined in your settings?

Comment: I have MEDIA_ROOT set to 'media'. There is a folder in my root called 'media' and this works when saving a file there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this to my urls.py file
   if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns.append(url(r'^media/(?P.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}))

and it works. no need to edit the template. the rfile.fileObject.url was enough without the MEDIA_URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. It might be possible that you are missing the static url path.

```
{{ STATIC_URL }}{{ rfile.fileObject }}
```

Comment: They aren't being saved into my static files folder they're being saved into the 'Media' folder in the project.